# AWS Import-Snapshot with shared S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, storage

I am currently looking for a way of easily distributing customised volumes to clients.
An approach I am looking at is creating RAW disk images, saving them to S3 and having clients import them as snapshots using the AWS CLI.
My question is - who pays for the data access request/data transfer?

...I'm assuming its bucket owner as there is no "requester-pays" option for the Import-Snapshot command. Has anybody done anything similar?

Another approach is directly sharing snapshots to a clients account - but this involves an added charge on our part to create the ideal sized volumes + generate the snapshots to share.
Is there a better method of generating + sharing data (essentially what would become EBS volumes) of varying sizes and content?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be to **create an Amazon Machine Image (AMI)**, which is a bootable snapshot. You can list this it as a **Community AMI**.

Your clients can **select the AMI when launching an Amazon EC2 instance**. The boot disk will be exactly as you configured -- with the operating system, your application and all configurations that were saved on the disk.

There is no cost to you when a client uses the AMI.

See: [Make an AMI public - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-intro.html)

Comment: Unfortunately providing AMI's doesn't work for us - ideally, dependent on their needs, we want clients to be able to connect one or more EBS volumes (formed from a snapshot (shared snapshot or from an imported disk image or other?)) to an AMI we provide separately. Is there a way of sharing customised "pluggable" storage modules enforcing requester-pays on an S3 bucket?

Comment: Additional Amazon EBS volumes can be attached to any Amazon EC2 instance. So, if they launch from your AMI, they can still attach additional volumes. If this is not suitable, please update your Question with more details to explain your situation.